# Got "failed: Data source does not exist" when running robot test cases via Jenkins

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, robotframework

I have configured my robot project with Jenkins on the windows machine.Provided commands in execute windows batch commands = robot -d robot_result --variable profile:NR Tests\Suite\Module
In the module folder, I have all the robot test cases. hence, provided the path of test cases.
But when I trigger build in jenkins I get below error

[ ERROR ] Parsing 'Tests\Suite\Module\' failed: Data source does not exist.

While same test cases are working file in Eclipse and command line with above-mentioned command. I am using python interpreter to execute test cases in windows machine.
Can someone please provide input?

Comment: Are working directories the same when you are running on jenkins and on local machine?

Comment: Yes, working directories are the same. but you know I travel till selenium root directory then execute below command in windows.    C:\User\Eric\folder1\projectrepo\seleniumRobot> robot -d robot_result --variable profile:NR Tests\Suite\Module   now, when jenkins does git pull it keeps all project in its workspace. how to specify in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are doing something like "robot foo.robot", but "foo.robot" doesn't exist. Either you have a typo in the filename, or you're making assumptions about the cwd that aren't true, or the file literally doesn't exist.